# Generate a random integer within a given range AND is even ONLY

Tags: java, random, integer

I am having trouble generating this code which I'm sure I'm just in a coder's block or something because it seems as though it should be easy but can't get it for the life of me.

I have a program which needs random numbers generated within a certain range which is to represent money. The stipulation is that the money need be in between 2 and 200 and represent only even dollars only so $2, $4, $6...so on. I have done extensive searching online which yield a bounty of code to represent random numbers in a range in java but not the part about being only even.

Any ideas?

Comment: get a random between 1 and 100 and multiply it by 2?

Comment: @Marcelo - or just mask off the low-order bit.

Comment: (This is blazingly simple.  How does an even number, in binary, differ from an odd number??)

Comment: @HotLicks Or divide it by two, cast to an int, and multiply it by 2.

Comment: ... or `(yourNum % 2 == 0 ? yourNum : yourNum + 1)`...

Comment: This question should be closed for lack of basic understanding and lack of effort...

Comment: @Marcelo - Why don't you post your suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @Marcelo's answer is the best one here and it's not even an answer!

Comment: @Omaha It may be the best, but is it the most clever??? :)

Comment: @FunkyT Imagine your professors face if you drop your code on his desk with some clever bit twiddling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be clever, you *could* make sure the least significant bit of the number is not set:

```
int num = (new Random().nextInt(199) & ~1) + 2;
```

This will ensure that the number is always even.

*Thanks Eyal Shneider and Omaha*

---

**Marcelo**'s comment from the OP is the correct answer, though.

Get a number between 1-100, and multiple by 2:

```
int num = (new Random().nextInt(100) + 1) * 2;
```

Comment: No it won't.  ORing anything with zero will result in the same value being returned.  3|0=3, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Should be fixed?

Comment: You can AND it with -2 instead.

Comment: Indeed, that's the change I was going to suggest.

Comment: @crush: ~1 is actually cleaner IMO :)

Comment: Lol. Do you really think? It does make it clearer what is happening. Won't it be 1 less operation though with -2?

Comment: @Marcelo I initially thought about that one hah. Figured double shifting would be too many instructions to achieve eliteness.

Comment: @crush: it is optimized by the compiler and results in the same bytecode (where the constant -2 is used)

Comment: Who would have thought such a bad question would be fun!

Comment: @EyalSchneider Well, in that case, back to `~1`. It looks way cooler, more hackerish?

Comment: worked like a charm that code snippet is clever. never would have came out of my head, that's how you know the weekend programmers from the program warriors. thx again

Comment: Hmm, I wonder which of the two methods above gets a more even distribution? Or are they destined to be equal? =)

Answer (score 0):

```
int rand = new Random.nextInt(200);
int result = 2;
while(result < rand) {
    result += 2;
}
return result;
```

(I'd make it recursive but I've got to go meet my wife for dinner.)